# Json Object with Quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, tagging

I have a json object that is being used here

```
var tagApi = jQuery(".tm-input").tagsManager({
      prefilled: ["Angola", "Laos", "Nepal"]
    });

    jQuery(".tm-input").typeahead({
      name: 'SEARCHVAR',
      limit: 3,
      prefetch: '../_realRETS/php/search/all.jsonp'
    }).on('typeahead:selected', function (e, d) {

      tagApi.tagsManager("pushTag", d.value);

    });
```

The file Contents of the Json File look as such...

```
["test's"]
```

However I get an error because of the single quotation... and have tried the following methods, please note if my methods "Should work" I would like to know about it regardless.

I've tried escaping the quote by using ["test\'s"] and also by using html encoding, however the encoding works, it shows up in the tag with the acctual encode text rather then the character.

Please help understand how I could use single quotes in this plugin.

Comment: In theory `\'` should work. Have you tried double-escaping: `\\'`?

Comment: When I double Escape the quote shows up with a backslash, when I escape normally it does not show a result, I'm assuming this is an error.

Comment: what is the specific error you get?

Comment: Not an error, but nothing shows up, thats the error... if you're fermilier with magicSuggest and Ajax if the file has an error in it at all, no results will populate.